# Combine Flash and JavaFX desktop

Tags: flash, javafx, desktop

That`s my first question there, and i hope to do it correctly!

I am creating a GUI for self-service kiosk, and i need to show advertising(on Flash, or smth like this), is in JavaFX ability for it?

All that i have found is about web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX does not render Flash content.

If your advertising is available in HTML5 format, use that instead by displaying the advertising in a JavaFX [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html).